# How would I draw a line between 2 world-coordinate points using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I have a basic 3D demo set up drawing lines with OpenGL using VAO's and shaders.

```
// Example vertices
float[] verts = { 
    1f, 1f, 1f,
    0f, 0f, 0f
};

// Loading to VAO etc. as standard and enabling shader here...

// Draw call
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
```

Vertex shader is basic, no model matrix in use at the moment:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

This outputs the line drawn properly in the 3D world, but the start/end points are based on the vertex positions only which isn't too useful.

My question is: how can I specify the start and end locations in my **world coordinates** and draw a line between those points?

I would imagine I need to somehow transform the position of each of the two vertices by a different model matrix, but it's not at all clear how this would work, and what the original vertices should be for the line.

Comment: Nah you'd apply the same transformation to both points. The transformation matrix needs to contain a scaling to (p2-p1) first and then a translation to p1(x,y,z). Oh and you chose the vertices of (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) correctly

Comment: I think I somewhat follow this logic, but the scaling part is not too clear to me. Would this work regardless of the xyz location of the points? Do I need to be concerned with rotation at all or does the scale and translate work regardless of the orientation of the line?

Comment: You don't really need to do any rotation if you just want to define a line between 2 lines in world-coordinates. Anyway I'm not sure the trouble is worth it, it might just be better write the vertices and update your vertex buffer.

Comment: What vertices would I use in that case though? I think I'm misunderstanding a little. Doing the scaling and translation sounds a bit cleaner to me, then I would only need to worry about the model matrix if the lines needed to change position I think? If you're able to post a full answer with some example code I'd be happy to check it and accept if it works for me. Thanks!